# How to use <br /> in a placeholder on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, textarea, placeholder

I have a textarea which is has Markdown support and I would like to show a placeholder to show what sort of formatting Markdown likes but putting `<br />` in the placeholder shows `<br />` in the text. I would prefer it to make a new line if this is possible.

I am using Rails 3, below is the code I am using:

`<%= f.text_area :info, :placeholder => "if you want you can <br /> add a link by doing this:  [text](http://link.com) it's pretty neat aye? or you could use bold by doing this: **bold text is cool**" %>`

Comment: Did u try \n instead of <br />?

Comment: Just tried that. It doesn't work in the textarea but viewing the source of the page, it shows a new line.

Comment: \n shows a new line in view source but not in the textarea. What's next to try?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-button-element.html#attr-textarea-placeholder), the placeholder attribute can't contain any line breaks or carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

As Logan says, though you can find some hacks in the similar question here:

[Can you have multiline HTML5 placeholder text in a <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189223/can-you-have-multiline-html5-placeholder-text-in-a-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more related hacks to multiline placeholders, I followed the example in the answer below to do my workaround:
[Insert line break inside placeholder attribute of a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea)

For rails, I thought this was useful if you want a gem to deal with placeholders:
[jquery-placeholder-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-placeholder-rails/).

However, you'll need the forked version of jQuery-placeholder that supports newline: [jQuery-Placeholder-Newlines](https://github.com/bradjasper/jQuery-Placeholder-Newlines)