# line break for a string placeholder in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: "Comment on your track or" + \n + "share your favorite lyrics" %>
```

How can I get the placebolder to line break like

Solution was just to add white space so the next line wraps:

```
placeholder: "Comment on your track or                         share your favorite lyrics" %>
```

Pretty ugly but least complicated

Comment: OP - it looks like you're building a text_area..like in a form yes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The newline character `\n` should be included between the double, however HTML does not allow for line feed, but Thomas Hunter suggested an [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843665/848250) which consists in using a bunch of white spaces, like so:

```
<%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: "Comment on your track or                  share your favorite lyrics" %>
```

You can also opt to use the `title` attribute instead.

Comment: For some reason it just ignores the /n and the output is Comment on your track orshare your favorite. any ideas? the \s produces a space but \n does nothing

Comment: Try with a lot of white spaces :)

Comment: yea the white space works now. It wasn't working in FF for some reason i had to add another white space

Answer (score 6):

In Ruby, in general `"\n"` is the new line character.

e.g.:

```
  puts "first line\nsecond line"
  => 
  first line
  second line
```

**However, in your case:**

you seem to try to use the newline character in an `.erb` expression `<%= ... %>`

That does not work, because that will only format the newline in the **raw HTML souce**, 
but in the **formatted HTML** you will not see the newline! :-)

**To see the newline in the formatted HTML**, you need to do something like this:

- either put the two strings in separate DIVs or SPANs
- or put a `<br />` in the string instead of the `"\n"` -- `<br \>` is the HTML newline symbol

Answer (score 1):

You're creating HTML code. HTML does not care about whitespace in the actual code. What you need is a break in the HTML itself. However, it seems per this other question [Can you have multiline HTML5 placeholder text in a <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189223/can-you-have-multiline-html5-placeholder-text-in-a-textarea) that HTML does not allow line breaks in the `placeholder` field.

Comment: the br tag doesnt escape the ruby string