# How to display Ruby button caption in multiple lines?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

How can I display `send or press enter` over 2 lines like this

```
   send 
or press enter
```

This is my code:

```
<%= f.button :submit , "Send or press enter"%>
```

which produces them in the same line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [line break for a string placeholder in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288971/line-break-for-a-string-placeholder-in-ruby)

Comment: it is not working in this case

Comment: @sreena Then please edit your question to say that it isn't and why it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.button :submit do %>
    Send or
    <br/>
    press enter
<% end %>
```

Comment: shows this error `{:type=>"submit"} is not a symbol nor a string`

Comment: <%= f.button type: 'submit' do %>
What rails version installed?

Answer (score 0):

I hate my solution.

In my css file I have

```
#generate-download-id {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

and in my .erb I have

```
<%= f.button :submit, "Generate Download", id:"generate-download-id" %>
```

The reason I hate this solution is:

1. You have to go into a debugger to get/guess the width of "Generate
   Download".
2. You are then dependent on css breaking the text where it
   wants rather than where you want.

If anyone has a better answer ... I'm all ears.