# placeholder text getting cut inside a textarea

Tags: html, cordova

```
<textarea class="skinCondition-field vlongtext clear ui-input-text ui-body-d ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" type="text" placeholder="Update details of your present skin condition (e.g. normal, dry, flaky, etc). Optionally, add details of any past skin conditions, medication or skin treatments/surgeries undergone. You may also upload images/reports, so that doctors understand your condition better." value=""></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
textarea.ui-input-text.skinCondition-field {
    height:10.5em;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: block;     
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    white-space: normal!important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

even tried

```
textarea.ui-input-text.skinCondition-field::-webkit-input-placeholder {white-space: normal!important; word-break: break-all !important;word-wrap: break-word !important;}
```

But the problem persists in galaxy s3 .

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

See if [this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6Suhx/1/) helps. !

Click on the above link.

```
textarea.ui-input-text.skinCondition-field {
    height:10.5em;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: block;     
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    white-space: normal!important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here, in this case, the questioner requires a MULTI-LINE PLACEHOLDER !
You can get the same, this way :

```
#text1::-webkit-input-placeholder::after {
    display:block;
    content:"Line 2\A Line 3";
}



#text2::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color:transparent;
}

#text2::-webkit-input-placeholder::before {
    color:#666;
    content:"Line 1\A Line 2\A Line 3\A";
}
```

Although, PLACEHOLDER text is only for short hints ! So, use a `<title>` instead, for longer texts.

Comment: Try replacing the default `<meta>` tag to this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />`

Comment: Still not working, but its working fine in Android 2.3.3., but not in versions 4.1.2

Comment: What happens exactly !? when you deploy the app to device ?

Comment: Tested in Emulators Android 2.3.3(in which it was working already) and Android  4.1.2 (not working),
Also in galaxy S3(not working) .

Comment: lemme deploy it to my app and see logcat !

Comment: Got your problem, after deploying. I have a Nexus 4, and it had the same issue. edited the answer. Hope it helps !

Comment: Saw similar one in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189223/can-you-have-multiline-html5-placeholder-text-in-a-textarea) , not working either. I guess <title> won't help in mobile apps. But why it works in 2.3.3 and not in 4.1.2.. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$('textarea')
    .addClass('placeholder')
    .each(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
    })

$('textarea').bind({
    'focus': function () {
        var placeholder = $(this).attr('placeholder');
        $(this)
            .removeClass('placeholder');

        if ($(this).val() == placeholder) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    },
    'blur': function () {
        var placeholder = $(this).attr('placeholder');

        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this)
                .val(placeholder)
                .addClass('placeholder');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try to remove your class then try

```
<textarea type="text" placeholder="Update details of your present skin condition (e.g. normal, dry, flaky, etc). Optionally, add details of any past skin conditions, medication or skin treatments/surgeries undergone. You may also upload images/reports, so that doctors understand your condition better." value=""></textarea>
```