# New line inside textarea placeholder via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I want to put a placeholder inside textarea via jQuery, but it does not work in Firefox.

Below is my code:

```
jQuery('#orderlink_bulk').attr("placeholder","ssss /n sss");
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to [escape string](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) in this case is to use `\n` instead of `/n`.

```
jQuery('#orderlink_bulk').attr("placeholder","ssss \n sss");
```

But it will not work for firefox as said in this thread:

[Can you have multiline HTML5 placeholder text in a <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189223/can-you-have-multiline-html5-placeholder-text-in-a-textarea)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a251gq60/)

Answer (score 1):

If you try to make a multiple line placeholder, it's not supported  as describe in the W3C documentation 
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute

this working good in Webkit with a `\n` but never work in FF 
http://jsfiddle.net/kyqo9xh8/