# multiline in placeholders in textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiline placeholder for which i have written a JS function.But the placeholder is shown empty. Inside my "blur" function I can see that consol.log is printing correctly line "data placeholder inside blur". What is incorrect here?

```
function textareaPlaceholderNewlines() {
    debugger;
    console.log("inside function");
    $('textarea[placeholder*="\n"]').each(function(){

        // Store placeholder elsewhere and blank it
        $(this).attr('data-placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder'));
        console.log("1");
        console.log("dataplaceholder " + $(this).attr('data-placeholder') )
        $(this).attr('dataplaceholder', '');
        console.log("2");

        // On focus, if value = placeholder, blank it
        $(this).focus(function(e){      
            if( $(this).val() == $(this).attr('data-placeholder') ) {
                $(this).attr('value', '');
                $(this).removeClass('placeholder');
                console.log("3");
            }               
        });                     

        // On blur, if value = blank, insert placeholder
        $(this).blur(function(e){
            if( $(this).val() == '' ) {
                $(this).attr('value', $(this).attr('data-placeholder'));
                console.log("value now is" + 'value' );
                console.log("data placeholder inside blur" + $(this).attr('data-placeholder'));
                $(this).addClass('placeholder');
                console.log("4");
            }
        });             

        // Call blur method to preset element - this will insert the placeholder
        // if the value hasn't been prepopulated
        $(this).blur();
    });

}
```

Comment: seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/slash197/xyv5k4p6/

Comment: Someone has been asking this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189223/can-you-have-multiline-html5-placeholder-text-in-a-textarea 

The official answer is that it's not allowed. However the following fiddle shows a (not necessarily elegant) solution for this: https://jsfiddle.net/39mptojs/4/