# Placeholder text only visible in Internet Explorer

Tags: css

I have a placeholder for the address form, to give visitors an example of how to format their address. The placeholder text is visible in IE, but the other browsers (chrome, firefox, safari) it is transparent.

How can I fix it so that it shows in all browsers?

```css
 .form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
          transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
}
.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #c0392b;
}
}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #c0392b;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Recipients Address</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter the address in the same format as you would write it on a envelope.

EXAMPLE:
Thomas Nolan Kaszas II
5322 Otter Lane
Middleberge FL 32068" rows="8"></textarea>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Works as expected for me. Chrome 44.0.2403.157

Comment: @Cheslab screenshot added

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: It is still works fine for me, though it doesn't look like in your screenshot yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have semi-transparent textarea which in combination with default gray placeholder color make the text totally unreadable. You can change placeholder's text color by using following set of rules

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#c0392b;}
::-moz-placeholder          {color:#c0392b;}/* Firefox 19+ */
:-moz-placeholder           {color:#c0392b;}/* Firefox 18- */
:-ms-input-placeholder      {color:#c0392b;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it could be one of two things:
1) Your RGBA you have the last value set to 0 which would make text completely invisible. try: `rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`

2) Try using `\n` for line breaks in your placeholder text instead of actual line breaks.

[Can you have multiline HTML5 placeholder text in a <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189223/can-you-have-multiline-html5-placeholder-text-in-a-textarea)

Comment: I changed the last value to a 5 but no changes. I updated the CSS in original posting.

Comment: It's appearing in my browser, it's just super faint.

Comment: @pwz2000 Last value should be between 0 and 1 where 0 means _invisible_ and 1 means totally _visible_. 50% transparent can be written as `0.5` and also `.5`