# How to add multi line place holder text in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, placeholder

How to add multi line place holder text in textarea? .

I got a solution like following but its not working im mossilla, safari.

Chrome works this way..

```
$('#nameTxtBox').attr("placeholder", "League Name \n 1-2 lines most designs");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189223/can-you-have-multiline-html5-placeholder-text-in-a-textarea

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately multi-line placeholders are not supported as a rule. Chrome does allow for newline characters, but support across platforms can be spotty. The recommended course of action would be to create shorter, single-line placeholders. If you absolutely need a multi-line placeholder, you can try this:

```
<textarea style='white-space:pre;' placeholder='Line 1

Line2'></textarea>
```

By adding the css attribute `white-space:pre`, you force the textarea to treat the placeholder text as preformatted text. Again, though, support is spotty.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This code**

just add "**&#10**" before the new line without space.

```
<textarea  placeholder='First Line &#10;Second Line &#10;Third Line' rows="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: worked for me in a form-builder situation where other options could not.