# Angular io: Adding multiple lines in placeholder

Tags: angular, textarea

I am having trouble adding multi-lines within a placeholder in a textarea. I have already tried \r\n and \n.

Here is the input:

```
    <textarea #textAreaRef name="list" placeholder="[BE#] \n[OSuffix] \r\n [suggestedQuarter]" name="inputText"
 [className]="errorMessages.length>0 ? 'text-area in-valid' :'text-area valid'" [ngModel]="inputText" (ngModelChange)="onInputChange($event)"
 (scroll)="onScroll($event)"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add your placeholder value like this `[placeholder]` if you are getting data from your properties - this might understand the data has a string and reads your encoding, moves it to your next line i hope so - if not use html encoding for binding break - if that too doesn't work use `attr` binding for your placeholder

I think anyone of the above works - happy coding !!

[[Can you have multiline HTML5 placeholder text in a <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189223/can-you-have-multiline-html5-placeholder-text-in-a-textarea][0]) check this for further update

Comment: Good !! Happy coding !