# how we can add multiline placeholder in text area input in safari browser?

Tags: html, css

I need to add multiline placeholder in `<textarea>` for safari browser how i can achieve that
`<textarea name="story" placeholder="Enter story\n next line\n more"></textarea>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you have multiline HTML5 placeholder text in a <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189223/can-you-have-multiline-html5-placeholder-text-in-a-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be many suggestions out there, including not really using the placeholder but showing the text in a div behind the textarea.

They seem a bit hacky (and some don't work on Safari).

The only way I could find to do it within the placeholder attribute is also somewhat hacky, but at least it seems to work on Safari and it is 'pure' placeholder.

Use a monospace font, set the number of cols and fill up each 'line' with spaces to make that number of cols.

Tested on Safari on iPad (IOS 14).

```css
textarea {
  font-family: courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textAreaMultiligne" 
          placeholder="Enter story         next line           more"
          rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>
```

Comment: this solution only works with fixed width text area input.

Comment: That is correct. I fear that to get anything more general you will have to use Javascript.