# placeholder sentence into new row

Tags: html, placeholder

I am looking for an solution. If there's no any, well I cannot help it :]

I like placeholder attribute quite a lot. Today/tonight I was making an contact form.

However I am wondering is there any solution to put an word/sentence into new row into placeholder...

Example:

```
You are suppoused,
to write an message to me...
```

Instead of:

```
You are suppoused, to write an message to me...
```

I hope there is an way. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea

Comment: Thanks for that link @alcidesqueiroz. That will work quite great.

Answer (score 1):

[From the WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-placeholder) (emphasis mine):

> 4.10.7.3.10 The placeholder attribute
>
> The placeholder attribute represents a short hint (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry when the control has no value. A hint could be a sample value or a brief description of the expected format. The attribute, if specified, **must have a value that contains no U+000A LINE FEED (LF) or U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR) characters**.

Seems like a pretty clear no.

Comment: I see... Well there are few samples from above as well as this:
https://github.com/bradjasper/jQuery-Placeholder-Newlines

However I am not sure if I am going to use whole plugin for one line of enter button :)

Thanks for info.