# How to give placeholder color?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi below text is a placeholder that is from js ,its color is `#ccc` .I need the textarea color as black ,right now it is taking placeholder color .

```
<textarea id="txt1" class="txt1 required" name="comment1"></textarea><br>


 var firstname = userModel.get('firstName');
  $('textarea#txt1').val('Hey ' +firstname+',\nTell us what is on your mind').css('color','#ccc');
    });
```

How to give different color for textarea and placehoder

Comment: Can you use `HTML5`? If yes then we can user html attribute  `placeholder`

Comment: yea i can use but how to display +firstname+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The placeholder text can be set using the `placeholder` attribute like so:

```
var name = "some name";

$('#txt1').attr('placeholder', 'Hey ' + name + ', Tell us what is on your mind');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rxhHS/1/

Comment: How to call the name then ? I am calling the first name and displaying in as a placeholder

Comment: just like you were doing before. I have updated it with a name variable

Comment: yea working fine ,but \n is not working ,how to give break in placholder

Comment: @prash, i'm not sure it is possible. please take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS

```
   .txt1{background-color:black;color:white;}
    #txt1::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: #ccc;
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSrHh/1/)

Comment: But i need it in js , "+firstname+"  I am calling the login name and displaying as placeholder

Comment: @prash your tag had css, so i thought of giving it as answer, please remove css tag if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

basically you are defining a color to the textarea. so it will be equal for all the text.

If you are using HTML 5 then we can write the textarea as follows.

```
<textarea id="txt1" 
    placeholder='Hey, Tell us what is on your mind' 
    class="txt1 required" name="comment1"></textarea>
```

But if you are not using HTML5, Then we can use a very good jQuery plugin (I personally used it)

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

**EDIT**

Want to add the name in `placeholder`.

```
var firstname = userModel.get('firstName');
$('textarea#txt1').attr('placeholder','Hey '+firstname+', Tell us what is on your mind');
```

Comment: but then how to display the name ...+firstname+'