# Linebreaks inside Primefaces Watermark

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I insert a line break inside a primefaces watermark?

I tried

```
<p:watermark  value="First Line &lt;br/&gt; Second Line}" for="txtMicMemoVal"  />


<p:watermark  value="First Line \\n Second Line}" for="txtMicMemoVal"  />
```

but both failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hy,
with `<p:watermark>` you can not do it.

but you can do it with attribute placeholder
you can find many example  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea)