# Using PHP to add line breaks to TextArea

Tags: php, html

I want to add Line break in a textarea placeholder using php.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">

<head>
  //stuff
</head>

<body>
  //stuff
  <div id="editContainer">
      <textarea id="note" name="note" placeholder="Placeholder Text"></textarea>
  </div>
  //stuff
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you okay with doing this using javascript ?

Comment: @jophab i prefer php but go ahead and answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Should Work:

```
<textarea placeholder="<?php
$data = 'Line Number One,-,Line Number Two';
$ndata = str_replace(',-,',"\n",$data);
print "$ndata"; ?>"></textarea>
```

You can change the `,-,` in the third line to anything that suits you.

Here's some pointers:

- Make sure you rename your file to .php
- Make sure you use a local server or online server to parse the code.
- HTML Comments are Written as `<!--Comment-->` not as `//comment`(that's JavaScript)

Comment: this won't do anything but add the literal text "\n" to the placeholder

Comment: @PootieTang It doesn't add a literal \n to the placeholder, it adds a new line. So the output is like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ds4vsvrn/1/) (separated onto two lines).

Comment: ah you're right, but that still doesn't add a linebreak to the textarea

Comment: And @cash.io.co wants to probably use php to make IE happy.

Comment: php has absolutely nothing to do with ie.. ie could care less how the page was rendered

Comment: @DavidvleggerWenher It's working in IE11 for me, but you're correct that it won't be a cross-browser solution. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea). The most consistent way to accomplish it is to use a div that overlays the textarea.