# make bootstrap input placeholder reponsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Right now my comment input looks like this [image: comment input field img]
but when I resize the window or display on a mobile device here is what I get [image]

How can I put line break or make it responsive like almost all bootstrap object ?

Comment: That depends on how it is implemented.  We need to see your html.  This [example](http://www.bootply.com/e9hBKKmCbz) responds fine.  Click one of the preview logos on the right side in purple to resize and see the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="1313 Mockingbird Ln                  Saginaw, MI 45100">

<textarea name="address" placeholder="1313 Mockingbird Ln                  Saginaw, MI 45100"></textarea>
```

Live [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9jga0jux/2/)

**For Futher Using Javascript**

Click [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea)