# How to add HTML line break within an input text placeholder

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a line break within my input text placeholder.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control ph" id="" placeholder="Qualification Education Background *">
</div>
```

I tried with

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control ph" id="" placeholder="Qualification\n</br> Education\n <br>Background *">
</div>
```

But it doesn't work. Would anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: Use a `<textarea>` or a `<div contenteditable='true'>` `<input>` does not render HTML. `<textarea>` doesn't render HTML but it can have more than one line. An element with `contenteditable` can render HTML but you'll need to use a little JS to mimic a placeholder probably.

Comment: [You can check on this link on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: @newlearner ,@zer00ne  I need to do with input text only

Answer (score 9):

input can't reach more than one line, so if you wanna make the input multyline use textarea. for make a line break in the placeholder of textarea use html entity-

```
&#10;
```

for example:

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <textarea class="form-control ph" rows="5" 
     placeholder="Qualification &#10;Education &#10;Background *"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry. not working

Comment: sorry, but you have to use textarea. as i say, input can have only one line. as in placeholer as in the text itself. the entity will work for the textarea

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is add the text as value, which respects the line break \n.

```
$('textarea').attr('value', 'This is a line \nthis should be a new line');
```

Then you could remove it on focus and apply it back (if empty) on blur

```
var placeholder = 'This is a line \nthis should be a new line'; $('textarea').attr('value', placeholder); $('textarea').focus(function(){ if($(this).val() === placeholder){ $(this).attr('value', ''); } }); $('textarea').blur(function(){ if($(this).val() ===''){ $(this).attr('value', placeholder); } });
```

Comment: This is a bad idea — would require handling two cases (when value is present; when it is not).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to position a label text instead a placeholder atribute and hide it  on click or focus (with js) to clear input.

Comment: I need to use input text only