# Break line when placeholder reach input width in primeng

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular-forms

I have an Input with a long placeholder.

I'm trying to make line breaks but I am not able to find a working solution .

I've tried to add `&#10;` and `\n` in the placeholder text but that's not working.

```
<input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Username &#10;UsernameUsername  UsernameUsername" />
```

[image: input placeholder]

Here's a stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-primeng?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert line break inside placeholder attribute of a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That input needs some height to wrap the whole placeholder so it is visible. Styling ::-webkit-input-placeholder or :: placeholder would make it appear on multiple lines. Turn off the encapsulation in order to this style work

CSS

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder,::placeholder {
  position:relative;
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-break: break-all;
  top:-20px;
}
```

HTML

```
  <input type="text" [inputStyle]="{'height':'40px'}"  placeholder="Username UsernameUsername  UsernameUsername" />
```

Class:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
...
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-primeng-nt3uvm)

Comment: not working in primeng autocomplete input , example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-primeng-buhnla?file=app%2Fapp.component.html