# How to fit a placeholder in the form?

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4, placeholder

I am working on the form as shown in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mt6pysrg/9/embedded/result) in which I want to fit a complete placeholder text in the form.

The HTML which I have used in order to make a small input form is:

```
<div class="container text-center ">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="ml-2" style="width:100%;text-align:left;" for="inputAddress">Hello World</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.">
   </div>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the fiddle so that I can see the complete placeholder text. At this moment, **I can see few words(not the complete statement)** as shown below in the image:

[image]

Comment: Make a line-break after "since"

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible. If you have that much text it's not a placeholder really is it?

Comment: @TA Can you make changes in the fiddle ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea

Comment: @flash See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea)

Comment: anyhow, input won't allow line-break, textarea is the proper tag to use for so much text ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert line break inside placeholder attribute of a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea)

Answer (score 2):

use textarea instead of input, that will give you multi-line display.

see this example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_textarea_placeholder

Answer (score 1):

You should try a `textarea` instead of an `input`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Bootstrap issue, but you can use CSS3 -placeholder like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/navcLefq/1/

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  white-space:pre-line;  
  position:relative;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  white-space:pre-line;  
  position:relative;

}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  white-space:pre-line;  
  position:relative;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  white-space:pre-line;  
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: in FF every things still stands on one line , it is unreadable, input should be turned into textarea for that amount of text anyway ;)