# Placeholder new line is not working on mobile

Tags: html

I have a `textarea` in which will not break line on mobile, only on desktop using  `&#13;&#10;`

```html
 <textarea class="fontRoundedLight" rows="15" cols="20" maximum-scale=1 placeholder="one line &#13;&#10; more text &#13;&#10; and more &#13;&#10; and more."></textarea>
```

On `iPhone Safari` i will see one line that breaks only when there is no space, and not when I ask it to .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert line break inside placeholder attribute of a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Not sure where is the answer both in the duplicate link or the comment here. As I said i did exactly what they offer in the answer and it doesn't work on Safari mobile.

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13231023/7616528