# Break line defaultvalue of textarea

Tags: textarea

I have textarea with defaultvalue like this:

```
<textarea>
  One Two Three
</textarea>
```

How can i display field like this:

```
One
Two
Three
```

Comment: Using what? JavaScript? CSS? Just plain HTML?

Comment: You can use js, css, add code to defaultvalue, ex One \n Two \n..., i just want when page is load, textarea display like that

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're referring to the placeholder, this has been answered on here: [Insert line break inside placeholder attribute of a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea)

Note there's no simple way, just some hacks that may work in some browsers and not others like using &#10 where you want the line break.

```html
<textarea placeholder="one&#10; two">
</textarea>
```

Depending on what you're going for you could set the width or use something like col="5" to force each word to the next line, but that also affects the user input.

Comment: I want it is defaultvalue because user can delete per line when they input per field, if it is placeholder, when input all placeholder is disappear.

Comment: per line of defaultvalue is guide to input, i want user delete per line to add info for that line, other line still appear

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area

Answer (score 0):

My solution [here](https://codepen.io/echovariables/pen/yLBbRpd?editors=1010)

I replace space character by `<br/>` tag

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
Break with \r\n with default text area. It will work.

```
"One\r\nTwo\r\nThree\r\nFour"
```