# newline char \n for <textarea> placeholder is ignored on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, newline, placeholder

I see that this question has been asked here already, but no answer was provided so far.
I'm trying to add a multi-line placeholder for a textarea using jQuery.
My code looks like this:

```
$('#ticket_id').attr('placeholder' , 'first line \nsecond line \nthird line')
```

this works great in Chrome, but fails to work on Safari.
I tried using 
 instead of \n but that failed to work at chrome as well.
\r\n did the same as \n, worked for chrome but not for Safari.

Any ideas what else can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert line break inside placeholder attribute of a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea)

Comment: The only thing that did work from all the suggestions there is Jason Gennaro's Function, but the problem is that my <textarea> is a required field. Therefore if the <textarea> is already filled with text before user's insertion, the required field become ineffective .

Comment: If this is a limitation of Safari, maybe one idea is to create a transparent div that sits on top of the textArea, and shows if the content is empty, and hides if not..

Answer (score 2):

This is maybe a Safari limitation, so one idea is to emulate the placeholder.

All we need to do is place transparent div over the top of the textarea, and then make this visible / invisible based on the value.

Also disable mouse select & pointer events to prevent the div capturing, these are just simple css `pointer-events` & `user-select` css properties..

Below is an example.

```js
const ta = document.querySelector('textarea');
const pp = document.querySelector('.placeholder');
console.log(ta);
ta.addEventListener('input', () => {
  pp.classList.toggle('hidden', ta.value !== '');
});
```

```css
.holder {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.placeholder {
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: silver;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.2rem;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
textarea {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="placeholder">
    This is the place holder<br>
    Multiline<br>
    Ok?
  </div>
  <textarea required="true" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Better solution than the background image hack. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Line breaks (\n) in a textarea field work as expected in Chrome. However, the Safari default stylesheet overrides these line breaks.

We can mock a placeholder by adding a background image to the text area.

If there is no text in the textarea, show the background image. If the textarea is in focus, or there is a value, don't show the background image.

```
<TextField
  onChange={onTexfieldChange}
  value={textAreaValue}
  id={'text-area-img-placeholder'}
  style={{backgroundImage: (textAreaValue) && 'none'}}
/>
```

I am using styled components in React, but you can replace `TextField` with HTML textarea.

The style attribute of the `TextField` ensures that if there is a value in the textarea (textAreaValue), the background image is removed.

```
#text-area-img-placeholder {
    background-image: url(./fileName.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

#text-area-img-placeholder:focus{
 background-image: none;
}
```

Add this CSS to cover the background image over the entire textarea. When the HTML is in focus, remove the background image.

Comment: I cannot believe that only Safari cannot display linebreaks inside textarea placeholders and such hacks are necessary. For multilingual sites you need to create such "background images" for each language. I hope the Safari developers fix this ASAP. Today is 2023-01-16.

Answer (score 1):

1. `&#x0a;` is used to break the line in placeholder.
2. For safari add additional script to handle multiple line placeholder. jQuery is required for below script.

```js
$(function() {
  var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
  
  // Disable for chrome which already supports multiline
  if (! (!!window.chrome && !isOpera)) {
    var style = $('<style>textarea[data-placeholder].active { color: #ccc; }</style>')
    $('html > head').append(style);
    
    $('textarea[placeholder]').each(function(index) {
      var text  = $(this).attr('placeholder');
      var match = /\r|\n/.exec(text);
      
      if (! match)
        return;
      
      $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
      $(this).attr('data-placeholder', text);
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).val(text);
    });
    
    $('textarea[data-placeholder]').on('focus', function() {
      if ($(this).attr('data-placeholder') === $(this).val()) {
        $(this).attr('data-placeholder', $(this).val());
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
    });
    
    $('textarea[data-placeholder]').on('blur', function() {
      if ($(this).val() === '') {
        var text = $(this).attr('data-placeholder');
        $(this).val(text);
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
<body>
   <textarea rows="5" placeholder="first line &#x0a;second line &#x0a;third line"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using &#x0a; does not work either on mobile Safari as of November 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Here one way how to set the linebreaks directly inside the string. However, it does not work in Safari either.

**HTML:**

`<textarea></textarea>`

**Javascript/Jquery:**

```
var placeholder_text = `• First line
• Second line
• Third line`;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('textarea').attr('placeholder', placeholder_text)
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gt1ry6d0/2/